# java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy my project on JBoss 6.0. I am using Netbeans 7.0.1, Spring 3.0.2 and JSF2.0. The project is running fine in Tomcat. But when I trying to deploy on JBoss, I am getting the following error:

```
       *** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

         vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/WebApplication3.war ->  
                           org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during 
                  deploy: vfs:///C:/jboss-      6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/WebApplication3.war


              DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
          Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss- 
        6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/WebApplication3.war" is in error due to the 
     following reason(s): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: 
     sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:246) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.7.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0]
```

Can anyone figure this out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251385/inject-spring-beans-into-ejb3

Comment: This lead to this improvement on Spring: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10441

It does not fix the issue (that was in the app code) but provides useful insight of what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It happened for me when I used Spring Configuration annotation like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ Config.class })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
   ...
}
```

When I renamed `Config.class` to `CoreConfig.class` the error occurred when starting jetty. this happened because the `CoreConfig.class` was in a different sub module of my maven project, so jetty couldn't see it (as it resolves dependencies through mvn local repository).

After calling 'mvn install' everything was fine again.

So this might not exactly your problem but it might help you. As your problem can be a packaging problem. Some class is not on the classpath maybe.