# sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java, spring-boot

While saving the object in db following exception thrown.
I search on internet but i am unable to find the solution.

Using Spring Boot, Spring-MVC, Hibernate

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1150) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1148) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1139) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:531) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:234) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:227) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:137) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
at
```

Dao Class
I am calling the save method

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Class<? extends E> daoType;

     public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public K save(E entity) {
        return (K) currentSession().save(entity);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring-framework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework dependencies -->

</dependencies>
```

i try this [java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823288/java-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-typenotpresentexceptionpro)

but not find the solution

Comment: What's your entity you going to save? show it dude